# Display google map based on coordinates

Tags: entities, location

I've a node with field that store coordinates (in a field with type [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield)).

Now I want to display google map block on page based on coordinates in that field. How should I do it? IS there any module that provide such functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module as it provides widget to change Display format for my geofield.